# Failed to register "bundle Identifier"

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle-identifier

A few days ago I bought a `React Native's` course on Udemy. 
Nowadays I have a problem with the configuration that realizes in XCode.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you must give it a name something like prueba.aa.Prueba you must add the name of your app

Answer (score 5):

From the message, it seems that the bundle identifier is already taken by someone else. use a different one.